# can't inner join multiple ids in laravel for datatable

Tags: php, laravel

i use this query in laravel but still not work

```
$query = DB::table('parks') 
      ->join('park_provinces', 'parks.province_id', '=', 'provinces.id')
      ->select('parks.id as id''main_image','news_time_date')
      ->get();
```

the value province_id=[34 35 36]

Comment: what is in `$data['id']` ? Also, you should add proper tags with the question.

Comment: i am sory  i was remove this codition in where codition..
is just a parameters

Comment: So, your `parks.province_id` is stored with `[` and `]` it's not just a single number?

Comment: it's not just one number, it uses a space separator for each number

Comment: then you can't run the `=` condition on this keys as they are not same. If you starting out, I'd suggest you to keep this values as comma separated string, not with space separated.

Comment: `->select('parks.id as id','main_image','news_time_date')` missing comma seperator

Answer (score 1):

As the value in the `province_id` is not number but string with space separated `ids` of the `provinces`, you can't apply the `=` in this case.
Instead you need to replace the `" "(space)` with `,(comma)` and use `find_in_set` method of `mysql`.

```
$query = DB::table('parks') 
      ->join('parks', function($query){
          $query->on(DB::raw('find_in_set(provinces.id, REPLACE(parks.province_id, " ", ",")'));
       })
      ->select('parks.id as id', 'main_image','news_time_date')
      ->get();
```